# Odoo 10 - Cancelled stock pickings can not be deleted, why?

Tags: postgresql, odoo-10, odoo

Why cancelled stock pickings can not be deleted in certain cases?

Specifically, I get the message that the item can not be deleted as it has a reference with: Packing Operation - stock.pack.operation]

When a cancelled stock picking can be deleted and when it can not be?

Answer (score 2):

If you get the message *[object with reference: Packing Operation - stock.pack.operation]*, it means that the picking was in *Available* state at least (it also could have been in *Done* state). And when the picking is in *Available* state, operations and stock move operation links are generated. If the picking is in *Done* state, quants for the moves are also generated.

In your case, as you were able to cancel the picking through the interface, it means that it didn't get to *Done* state, so quants weren't generated yet. So you can execute the following queries in PostgreSQL:

Imagine that your picking has the ID 88:

```
DELETE FROM stock_move_operation_link WHERE operation_id IN (SELECT id FROM stock_pack_operation WHERE picking_id=88);
DELETE FROM stock_pack_operation WHERE picking_id=88;
DELETE FROM stock_move WHERE picking_id=88;
DELETE FROM stock_picking WHERE id=88;
```

**What is `stock_move_operation_link` used for**

When you create a picking, for example, with three lines:

- Product A (3 units)
- Product A (7 units)
- Product B (6 units)

And then you mark it as to do, operations are generated this way (if you don't specify any lot):

- Product A (10 units)
- Product B (6 units)

So in `stock_move_link_operation` you'll be able to see, among other data, which moves belong to each operation.

Comment: Thanks forvas, what is stock_move_operation_link used for?

Comment: @M.E. In core, the comment is that it "Makes a link between `stock.move` and `stock.pack.operation` in order to compute the remaining quantities on each of those objects."

Comment: It's for what @travisw said, I've edited my answer to put an example if it helps you to understand it better.

Comment: @M.E. if any of the answers was useful for you, please check it as correct to set the question as closed.

Comment: forvas your answer is defintively helpful, but it involves direct action on database (I am sure we all agree that it is not the best scenario). I prefer to wait and see if someone can further elaborate @travisw answer. I can't follow this action he mentions: __You'll most likely need to Mark As Todo__ I hope someone can provide any idea on why I can't see __Mark As Todo__ or where that action/option is in the user interface

Answer (score 2):

@forvas gives a good explanation of the problem but you don't need to resort to psql to resolve this (although you can).

Cancelling the picking only cancels the Moves (Initial Demand tab). You can't delete the picking if it has Operation lines still. You'll most likely need to Mark As Todo so that you can see the Operations tab to delete each line. At that point you can delete the entire picking.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to detele each line in operations? Actually I have no Operations tab and I can't mark anything as "Mark As Todo".

Answer (score 0):

I think you may **return the same picking** is better than manual deleting the same from the back end side. Because there some Quant related transaction is little bit difficult to remove from the backhand side